# How to start an activity via a service after rebooting

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I need my app to start running (in the background) after rebooting the device. Here's what I've come up with till now (after taking a lot of help from here...)

This is my BootUpReceiver making use of broadcastreceiver:

```
public class BootUpReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, RebootService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("caller", "RebootReceiver");
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }
}
```

This is the service class:

```
public class RebootService extends IntentService{

    public RebootService(String name) {
        super(name);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);  
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        String intentType = intent.getExtras().getString("caller");
        if(intentType == null) 
            return;
        if(intentType.equals("RebootReceiver")) 
            getApplication().startActivity(i);            
    }
}
```

THis is my android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootUpReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".RebootService"/>
</application>
```

The problem is, When I install this on my phone and reboot, the app crashes: It says, "Transfer has stopped working". After I press the OK button, when I check the app info, the app is running.

I'm new to android and I'm not sure what is going on. Am I supposed to add any more permissions?

Kindly help.
TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem lies with your RebootService constructor.  When the system invokes it, it doesn't provide any arguments, so it's going to crash.  If you look in the logs you'll probably see something to the effect of "Unable to instantiate service..."

Try replacing your constructor with:

```
public RebootService() {
    super( "Reboot Service" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me try this out and get back to you.. I did find the constructor fishy

Comment: UPDATE: IT WORKS. Now the activity starts up when i reboot.. but what i really wanted is for the app to start in the background :|

Comment: That is a problem with your design rather than problems with your code.  You're starting an Activity, which is going to come up in the foreground.  If you want it in the background then you'll have to do whatever you're doing in your Service and not start an Activity.